# How to skip the most recent item from a BehaviorSubject on one of the subscribers in RxJava?

Tags: asynchronous, rx-java2

I have an Observable source where several items are emitted. For each item, I need to execute a long process in the background and start each process only after the previous one is completed. So, I get the desired behavior using these operators:
[image: Desired behavior]

'0, 1, 2, 3' are observable items, 'A, B, C' are process results. I start the processing of '0' manually using `startWith` to start this processing circle. The problem is that 'A, B, C' are emitted by  BehaviorSubject (in other places I need the latest calculation result), so if I have already processed the old items, the BehaviorSubject returns the old result and then I get the following:
[image: Actual behavior]

So how can I skip that old result 'X'? If I use skip(1) then the result 'A' is skipped if there is no processing before. Or maybe there is another more appropriate way to reach my goal?

A bit of code to bring specifics, what am I doing:

```
val decodedChannelsSource =
    BehaviorSubject.create<List<ChannelData>>()

fun startTransmitting(channels: List<ChannelData>, frameSize: Int, frameCount: Int) {
    transmitSubscription?.dispose()
    transmitSubscription = Observable
        .create<List<ChannelData>> {
            for (i in 1 until frameCount) {
                val chls = channels.map { c ->
                    c.apply { frameData = UserDataProvider.generateData(frameSize) }
                }
                it.onNext(chls)
            }
        }
        .zipWith(decodedChannelsSource) { trans, rec -> trans }
        .startWith(channels.map { c ->
            c.apply { frameData = UserDataProvider.generateData(frameSize) }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe{ processChannels(it) }
}

fun processChannels(channels: List<ChannelData>) {
    ... // do calculations with channels in the background
    decodedChannelsSource.onNext(channels)
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `BehaviorSubject`? Can't you use `PublishSubject`? You could wire up a `PublishSubject` to the `BehaviorSubject` and then zip on the `PublishSubject` so you always get the live signals only.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "wire up subjects", so I just create a new `PublishSubject` and emit the same items to it using `onNext()` where `BehaviorSubject` also uses this method.

Comment: `subject1.subscribe(subject2)`